# Test implementation of abstract class, many constructors

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I want to test abstract class. I wrote many test methods that works on abstract code. Now I want to test implementation. My test class is also abstract, and it have method `MyAbstractClass CreateInstance()`. Unfortunately, my implementation has two constructors, and each constructor have 2 parameters. I don't want to create 4 test classes which inherits base abstract test, because it's too much code.
Is it possible to run same test with different parameters of constructor? For example I have test method XYZ and I want to run this method 4 times with different instance of abstract class.

Comment: I'm quite puzzled by how can an abstract class have a method to create instance... isn't it impossible by definition?

Comment: That method is also abstract. You need to provide implementation fior this method in inherited test class.

Comment: Why just don't use some mocking library? F.e NSubstitute.

Comment: Isn't the abstract part a red herring here? OP has no problem with this (he will create a concrete test class), the question is how to test a class with multiple constructors.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could replace `CreateInstance()` with `CreateInstances()` and iterate on the instances to test them.

A concrete implementation with 2 totally different constructors is probably a code smell though.

Comment: I thought about it. Maybe a code smell, but first ctor gets float[] as argument, and second short[] as argument, so only small conversion occurs. How to iterate over these instances using MSTest tools? Any attibues? Initialization before test? I think foreach loop in every test method is not good idea.

Comment: I was thinking foreach loop in abstract test method - weird indeed but does the trick.

Comment: If I were you, I'd write 2 different derived test classes for the 2 constructors though. More work but more logical.

Comment: I did that @guillaume31. But I thought there is more elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create an instance of an abstract class, so there's no way you would be able to test it. It's like you wanted to test an interface...

You can only test derived classes, or just don't make the class abstract if you need to test it.

Comment: I'm testing abstract class. I have many test for abstract class. In my abstract test class, I have abstract GetInstance method. This method should be implemented in inherited test class. Inherited test class will create concrete implementation of abstract class under test.